# RSA: Know the public key from a pair of plain text and their cipher?

Tags: rsa

I have two plain texts files cipher with RSA (with the same public and private key) and I have their cipher texts too. Would it be possible know the public key from that information?

My messages have 10 characters and I cannot calculate a huge exponential operation. No padding is used on the messages before encryption.

Comment: What are the ciphertext sizes in bits? What is the source of this question?

Comment: Cipher text have a size of 128 bytes. The messages are "First test" and "Second test"

Comment: Suggestion: maybe you converted your plaintexts into integers incorrectly. Did you try little endian or big endian?

Answer (score 2):

From a couple of plaintext/ciphertext $(m_1, c_1)$ and $(m_2, c_2)$, then the modulus $n$ is a factor of
$$
\gcd(m_1^e-c_1, m_2^e-c_2).
$$
The explanation is that
$$
c_i = m_i^e - \lambda_i n
$$
for some unknown $\lambda_i$, so $n$ both divides $m_1^e-c_1$ and $m_2^e-c_2$.

Of course, this solution works if you know $e$, but it can be tried with some classically used values ($e=3$ for instance).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That it is what I tried and I have not any result yet. I tried with the first 8000 numbers and the first 4 fermat numbers. I hope that I come up with the e value or with another way to solve this problem

Comment: The most used value for $e$ is $65537$, so if you can manage exponentiation with it, you may find something.

Comment: I know, 65537 is the 4th fermat number and I tried with it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @root2d3877 Are you sure that the plaintext values are not padded somehow?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, I am. The problems says that there is no padding